# meteor:easy-search first query returns empty

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-easy-search

Using meteor easy-search I have an Index on my user collection :

```
UserIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
    collection: Meteor.users,
    fields: ['username', 'realname', 'bio', 'email'],
    engine: new EasySearch.MongoDB(),
});
```

And a query in my client :

```
var userResults = UserIndex.search(input).fetch();
```

The first time I fetch for an input, the index returns empty, the second time it works normally. It works that way when I change inputs: first time empty, second time works ok. I have no clue why it behaves that way... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give time for your search results to be published to the client. Try wrapping your search in a [`Tracker.autorun`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun), like:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  let userResults = UserIndex.search(input).fetch();
  console.log(userResults);
});
```

Watch the logged results after making one search; they'll start empty but then as the results are published to the client, you'll see the proper results logged.